# How to extract URLs using regex in R based on some criteria?

Tags: r, regex, rvest

I need to extract some specific URLs from the list of URLs which are listed at the bottom of the question that I extracted using `rvest`

However, I only need to extract the URLs that begin with one of the following

- `/assets/`
- `/data`
- `/files/`

and contain one of the following words (case insensitive)

- `primary`
- `elem`
- `midd`
- `high`

but not when the URL begins with `/files/` which then must contain `data-for-researchers/` only

I'm using R; so I used `rvest` to extract the data:

**CODE**

```
url %>%
        html_nodes("a") %>% html_attr("href") %>%
        str_subset(regex("^//*(assets|data|files).*((Primary|Elem|Midd|High)|(data-for-researchers))", ignore_case = T))
```

This works for the most part - i.e. it pulls almost all of the URLs I need, but it gives me a couple of extra from the URLs that begins with `\files\`.

**Example - where the regex works**

```
[1] "https://www.ed.sc.gov/assets/reportCards/2008/documents/Primary_School_Performance_File_2008.xls"                     
 [2] "https://www.ed.sc.gov/assets/reportCards/2008/documents/Primary_School_Fact_File_2008.xls"                            
 [3] "https://www.ed.sc.gov/assets/reportCards/2008/documents/2008-ELEM-Schools-Performance-Data.xls"                       
 [4] "https://www.ed.sc.gov/assets/reportCards/2008/documents/Elementary_School_Fact_File_2008.xls"                         
 [5] "https://www.ed.sc.gov/assets/reportCards/2008/documents/2008-MIDDLE-Schools-Performance-Data.xls"                     
 [6] "https://www.ed.sc.gov/assets/reportCards/2008/documents/Middle_School_Fact_File_2008.xls"
```

**Where the code is not working**

```
/files/2018/data-files/high-school-ela-math-results/                                
/files/2018/data-files/elementary-middle-ela-math-results/                          
/files/2018/data-files/2018-report-card-data-for-researchers/                       
/files/2018/data-files/2018-report-card-data-for-researchers-additional-information/
```

but I only want the 3rd from this list while keeping all the other that I matched for the other ones using the code above.

I tried so many variants of regex pattern but it mostly only removed the bottom 2 from above.

How can I fix this?

**DATA**

I'm adding the link to the file where I put the `dput` of all data as the list is too long to post. It can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4du4x0gbw4oymay/dput.txt?dl=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

url %>%
  html_nodes("a") %>% html_attr("href") %>%
  str_subset(regex('(assets/|data/).*((Primary|Elem|Midd|High))|(files.*data-for-researchers/)', ignore_case = TRUE))
```

Or using `grep` in base R :

```
grep('(assets/|data/).*((Primary|Elem|Midd|High))|(files.*data-for-researchers/)',
     x, value = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)
```

where `x` is the string.

Comment: That's awesome! I see where I made the error. Thanks!.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can do a conditional in regex. So I would suggest to do this step in two steps and combine the lists.

```
most_data <-
    url %>%
    html_nodes("a") %>% html_attr("href") %>%
    str_subset(regex("^//*(assets|data).*((Primary|Elem|Midd|High)|(data-for-researchers))", ignore_case = T))

remaining_data <-
    url %>%
    html_nodes("a") %>% html_attr("href") %>%
    str_subset(regex("^//*files.*((Primary|Elem|Midd|High)|(data-for-researchers))", ignore_case = T))

all_data <- c(most_data, remaining_data)
```

You may have to update the above based on your data. But I hope the general approach makes sense.